# Vertical alignment is not pixel perfect

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

I am trying to vertically align title inside navigation panel.
 **However, when I inspect screenshoted image in an image viewer, I found out, that vertical alignment is pixel imperfect. 1px gap from bottom.**

[image: Navigation panel]
[image: Zoomed navigation panel]

*I did the following:*

- 1. Try: Let the flexbox vertical align H1 with uniform distribution of
     bottom and top margin. I am using `bootstrap 4` util classes. However,
     one pixel gap was still remaining.
- 2. Try: Navigation panel has explicitly defined **height of 50px**. I tried to set `line-height` on H1 element which equals to the height of navigation bar. So when the `font-size` is `13px`, I expected that spacing above and bottom of the text will be the same 50px - 13px equals = 37px. This result, 37px should be divided uniformly between top and bottom -  18,5px. But what about half pixels, do they work? Still issue is remaining.
- 3. Try: Make font bigger to fill the 1px gap. So that font-size is set on 14px. 50px - 14px equals 36px, so I would assume that remaining space will be divided uniformly between top and bottom spacing - 18px. However, no changes occurred.

You can notice that a 1px font-size does not really match one pixel physically.

> Is it possible vertically align with pixel perfection for given
>   example? Could it be problem with used font? Is it problem with browser engine?

**HTML snippet 1.try :**

```
<nav>
      <div class="navbar navbar-expand-md p-0 pr-3 bg-dark align-items center">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand p-0">
                <img src="#" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
            </a>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <div class="navbar-nav w-100">
                    <h1 class="m-auto">
                        Air Quality Management System of the City of Olomouc
                    </h1>
                   <div class="flag-container">
                        <a class="mr-2" href="#">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="#" alt="cs flag">
                        </a>
                        <a class="mr-2" href="#">
                            <img class="img-fluid active" src="#" alt="en flag">
                        </a>
                   </div>
               </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</nav>
```

**HTML snippet 2.try :**

```
<nav>
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-md p-0 pr-3 bg-dark align-items center">
        ... abrev. ...
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <div class="navbar-nav w-100">
                <h1 class="mx-auto my-0">
                    Air Quality Management System of the City of Olomouc
                </h1>
              ... abrev. ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS snippet:**
Additional css rules which I added, rest are implicitly from bootstrap 4.

```css
nav .navbar-brand img {
    max-height: 50px;
    padding-left: .25rem;
    background-color: #f10;
}

nav h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-size: .8125rem;
    font-family: 'Hind';
    letter-spacing: .15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**CSS snippet for 2. try:**
I added line-height equals to height of navigation bar

```
nav h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-size: .8125rem;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 50px;
 }
```

Comment: *I tried to increase the font by one pixel up (14px) to erase the gap. However, it did not even help.*". Why? What happened when you did that? What exactly do you *want* to happen? Also, you'll need to provide enough code to duplicate the whole navbar, not just the`<h1>` tag for us to really be able to help.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Ok, ill try to more specify question.

Answer (score 0):

You have nav h1. Should be `h1{` or `.m-auto h1{` or `.navbar-nav h1`.
To center the text do:

```
.navbar-nav h1 {
  ... your code ...
  vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are already using flexbox (because of the class `d-flex`), but if so, you could use the property `align-items: center` to align the content.

For example:

```css
.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #000;
}
.navbar-nav h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: .8125rem;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 50px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="navbar-nav d-flex w-100">
  <h1 class="m-auto">
    Air Quality Management System of the City of Olomouc
  </h1>
  <div class="flag-container">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```